# spark map eats my back slashed/ escaped strings

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, escaping

For some reason when I execute code in a map function it does not work but outside of the map function it works. I have some json and for some reason one of the tags has double quotes around result even thought it is well formed json. And all the double quotes around inside this string are escaped "\". I want to remove all the "\" and the two quotes. This works well:

```
val  d = dapiRdd take 1
d.foreach{ d1 =>  println(d1.replace("\\", "").replace("\"{","{").replace("}\"","}"))  }
```

however this code fails to remove the two double quotes and backslashes

```
val dapiRdd = sc.textFile(f).map(d=> d.replace("\\", "").replace("\"{","{").replace("}\"","}") )
```

It seems the passing this escaped string to an RDD to execute is causing the backslash to be stripped. Any thoughts here?

Clarification:
The output that I want and get from the first code snippet is

```
<json here>,"body":{"a":1, "b":"stuff"},<more Json>
```

the input and result that I don't want from the second code snippet looks like this

```
<json here>,"body":"{\"a\":1, \"b\":\"stuff\"}",<more Json>
```

The body is well formed json but spark interprets it as a string when I use the json parsing. So I want to remove the surrounding Quotes and all the escape/backslashes. I have code that works on the string but when I put that code inside of the spark rdd map function it has no effect. Why would the code not have an effect inside the spark Map function?

Comment: could you provide some more details, and an example that demonstrates the behavior?  What do you mean the backslash is being stripped?  Isn't that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Works for me using the above `map` line.  Can you submit a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: how are you printing/seeing the "result" ?

Comment: dataframe show is how I'm printing that dataframe. I believe the println was self explanatory for the non dataframe example.